# Calling internal api from another api function

Tags: python-3.x, rest, fastapi

I have implemented two endpoints:

```
Post -  /users/  #endpoint to add a user
Post - /confirmemail/  #endpoint to confirm email
```

Now I have function implemented for both endpoints, But I am thinking of calling the email endpoint after adding the user, directly. How can I achieve this in Fastapi?

Comment: Why do you need to call an API if you're running in the same program? Won't a function call do get the job done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one of your functionality will be used by multiple endpoints, you may need to extract it into a separate function (decoupling), for example:

```
def send_confirm_email():
    pass
```

Then call it in different endpoints:

```py
from .utils import send_confirm_email

@app.post("/users")
def add_user():
    # ...
    send_confirm_email()
    return {"message": "User added, confirm email sent."}

@app.post("/confirmemail")
def confirm_email():
    send_confirm_email()
    return {"message": "confirm email sent."}
```

Comment: I have added both the endpoints in the different routers, So I  was thinking of making this call generic